# How do I properly use theme overrides for the MUISwitch "bar" color when checked?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

After perusing the [source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Switch/Switch.js) I've tried the following, which works but generates a warning in the console.

```
const myTheme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiSwitch: {
      checked: {
        "& + $bar": {
          opacity: 1.0,
          backgroundColor: "rgb(129, 171, 134)" // Light green, aka #74d77f
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The error/warning I get is:

```
Warning: Material-UI: the `MuiSwitch` component increases the CSS specificity of the `checked` internal state.
You can not override it like this: 
{
  "checked": {
    "& + $bar": {
      "opacity": 1,
      "backgroundColor": "rgb(129, 171, 134)"
    }
  }
}

Instead, you need to use the $ruleName syntax:
{
  "&$checked": {
    "& + $bar": {
      "opacity": 1,
      "backgroundColor": "rgb(129, 171, 134)"
    }
  }
}
```

I can't figure out how to do this properly.

Update:

I got a fine solution below but my code also has an overwrite of the secondary color which is different, and the new rule overwrites that one as well.

```
colorSecondary: {
        "&$checked": {
          "& + $bar": {
            opacity: 0.3,
            backgroundColor: "white"
          }
        }
`
```

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE** - The original question was for v3 of Material-UI. In v4, the "bar" CSS class was renamed to "track". The examples in the answer have been updated for v4.

---

The following syntax works:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiSwitch: {
      track: {
        "$checked$checked + &": {
          opacity: 1.0,
          backgroundColor: "rgb(129, 171, 134)" // Light green, aka #74d77f
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit Switch bar color]

`$checked` is in there twice in order to increase the specificity to match the specificity of the default styling.

If you need to handle the three different color choices differently, then you can do something like the following:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Switch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiSwitch: {
      track: {
        "$checked:not($colorPrimary):not($colorSecondary) + &": {
          opacity: 1.0,
          backgroundColor: "rgb(129, 171, 134)"
        },
        "$checked$colorPrimary + &": {
          opacity: 1.0,
          backgroundColor: "purple"
        },
        "$checked$colorSecondary + &": {
          opacity: 1.0,
          backgroundColor: "pink"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
function App() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Switch color="default" />
      <Switch color="primary" />
      <Switch color="secondary" />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit Switch bar color]

Comment: That worked fine but unfortunately my case was a little more complicated because I want a different appearance for a secondary-styled switch:
`colorSecondary: {
        "&$checked": {
          "& + $bar": {
            opacity: 0.3,
            backgroundColor: "white"
          }
        }
`
and with your solution, the rule overwrite the colorSecondary rule whereas I only wanted to overwrite the base "checked" rule

Comment: I've added to my answer to show how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
const myTheme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiSwitch: {
      root:{
        "&$checked": {
          "& + $bar": {
            "opacity": 1,
            "backgroundColor": "rgb(129, 171, 134)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

In fact you should wrap the `"&$checked"` or `"&$disabled"`, ... inside `root`.

By the way, `createMuiTheme` is depricated, use `createTheme` instead.