# How can I override the style of the Material UI switch component when checked?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to control the color of the switch component, both when it is checked and when is is unchecked. By default it is red. I want the "ball knob" to be yellow when the state of the switch is `checked: true` and I want it to be grey when is it `checked: false`

I **must** be achieving the styling with the use of `createMuiTheme` and `ThemeProvider` I cannot be using classes directly on the component due to the nature of my project.

I have tried to follow the styling example of their custom purple knob here: https://codesandbox.io/s/x8bz8
Source: https://material-ui.com/components/switches/

Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out how to controle the color the the ball when it is checked (it always falls back to the default red). I have succeeded setting the colors of the track when both checked and not checked, and I have also been able to set the color of the ball when it is not checked. Can someone help me figure out how I can apply color style to the ball when it is checked?

I have made a CodeSandbox where I have been messing around: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-b6153

```
 const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
      MuiSwitch: {
        switchBase: {
          color: "#ccc", // this is working
          "&$checked": { // this is not working
            color: "#f2ff00"
          }
        },
        track: { // this is working
          opacity: 0.2,
          backgroundColor: "#fff",
          "$checked$checked + &": {
            opacity: 0.7,
            backgroundColor: "#fff"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <FormGroup>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Switch
              checked={state.checkedA}
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="checkedA"
            />
          }
          label="Custom color"
        />
      </FormGroup>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
```

I have also tried this:

```
checked: {
  "& + $bar": {
    opacity: 1.0,
    backgroundColor: "rgb(129, 171, 134)" // Light green, aka #74d77f
  }
},
```

Which was proposed in this answer to a somewhat similar question: [How do I properly use theme overrides for the MUISwitch "bar" color when checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55948999/how-do-i-properly-use-theme-overrides-for-the-muiswitch-bar-color-when-checked) but that does not seem to be working for what ever reason, maybe differences in MUI version or because the styles are different when created within `createMuiTheme`.

Comment: FYI - I've updated my answer in the other question you referenced. The original answer was for v3 of Material-UI. In v4, "bar" was renamed to "track".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Switch [defaults to using the secondary color](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.0/packages/material-ui/src/Switch/Switch.js#L156).

The color of the thumb is then controlled within the `colorSecondary` CSS. Here are the [default styles](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.0/packages/material-ui/src/Switch/Switch.js#L82) for that class:

```
  /* Styles applied to the internal SwitchBase component's root element if `color="secondary"`. */
  colorSecondary: {
    '&$checked': {
      color: theme.palette.secondary.main,
      '&:hover': {
        backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.secondary.main, theme.palette.action.hoverOpacity),
        '@media (hover: none)': {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        },
      },
    },
    '&$disabled': {
      color: theme.palette.type === 'light' ? theme.palette.grey[400] : theme.palette.grey[800],
    },
    '&$checked + $track': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
    '&$disabled + $track': {
      backgroundColor:
        theme.palette.type === 'light' ? theme.palette.common.black : theme.palette.common.white,
    },
  },
```

You can adjust the checked color in your theme with the following (which shows overriding both the thumb and the track):

```
  const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
      MuiSwitch: {
        switchBase: {
          // Controls default (unchecked) color for the thumb
          color: "#ccc"
        },
        colorSecondary: {
          "&$checked": {
            // Controls checked color for the thumb
            color: "#f2ff00"
          }
        },
        track: {
          // Controls default (unchecked) color for the track
          opacity: 0.2,
          backgroundColor: "#fff",
          "$checked$checked + &": {
            // Controls checked color for the track
            opacity: 0.7,
            backgroundColor: "#fff"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

[image: Edit customize Switch via theme]

---

#### For MUI v5

For v5, the structure of the object passed to `createTheme` changed. Another change is that `primary` is now the default color rather than `secondary`, so the `colorPrimary` styles need to be overridden instead of `colorSecondary`.

Here is the equivalent code for v5:

```
import React from "react";
import FormGroup from "@mui/material/FormGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import Switch from "@mui/material/Switch";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

export default function CustomizedSwitches() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    checkedA: true
  });

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
  };

  const theme = createTheme({
    components: {
      MuiSwitch: {
        styleOverrides: {
          switchBase: {
            // Controls default (unchecked) color for the thumb
            color: "#ccc"
          },
          colorPrimary: {
            "&.Mui-checked": {
              // Controls checked color for the thumb
              color: "#f2ff00"
            }
          },
          track: {
            // Controls default (unchecked) color for the track
            opacity: 0.2,
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            ".Mui-checked.Mui-checked + &": {
              // Controls checked color for the track
              opacity: 0.7,
              backgroundColor: "#fff"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <FormGroup>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Switch
              checked={state.checkedA}
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="checkedA"
            />
          }
          label="Custom color"
        />
      </FormGroup>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit customize Switch via theme]

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryan. I was really unable to extract that information from MUIs documentation. I spent a lot of time experimenting. I was previously overriding styles of the slider component and that went so much more smooth and was way way easier. This one was a little more tricky. Thanks!

Comment: any ideas for MUI v5?

Comment: @henk I've added a v5 example.

Answer (score 9):

**try this**

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({  
    switch_track: {
        backgroundColor: "#f50057",
    },
    switch_base: {
        color: "#f50057",
        "&.Mui-disabled": {
            color: "#e886a9"
        },
        "&.Mui-checked": {
            color: "#95cc97"
        },
        "&.Mui-checked + .MuiSwitch-track": {
            backgroundColor: "#4CAF50",
        }
    },
    switch_primary: {
        "&.Mui-checked": {
            color: "#4CAF50",
        },
        "&.Mui-checked + .MuiSwitch-track": {
            backgroundColor: "#4CAF50",
        },
    },
}));

<Switch
  classes={{
    track: classes.switch_track,
    switchBase: classes.switch_base,
    colorPrimary: classes.switch_primary,
  }}
  color={!disabled ? "primary" : "default"}
  checked={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
  name="<your_name>"
  disabled={disabled}
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Answer for MUI v5

```
export const lightTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiSwitch: {
      styleOverrides: {
        switchBase: {
          color: "#E60060",
          "&.Mui-checked": {
            color: "#16DF97"
          }
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Alternativly

```
<Switch
 name="mySwitch"
 checked={isChecked}
 onChange={handleChange}
 sx={{
  "&.MuiSwitch-root .MuiSwitch-switchBase": {
    color: "red"
  },

  "&.MuiSwitch-root .Mui-checked": {
   color: "green"
  }
 }}
/>
```