# Material UI - How can I override a Switch component's track styling at the theme level for both checked and unchecked states?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

In material UI, I'm attempting to override the `Switch` component's styling at the theme level, but the documentation for overriding such a value is pretty confusing.

```
createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
            type: darkMode ? 'dark' : 'light',
            background: {
                default: darkMode ? '#000' : '#f00',
            },
        },
        overrides: {
            MuiSwitch: {
                track: {
                    backgroundColor: '#3196E3',
                    opacity: 1,
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

That overrides the track's color, but it's really unclear just how to specify a different color when the `Switch` is checked. Here's what I'm getting. . . .[image]

I'm aware that there are similar posts that attempt to address the same question (e.g., [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63249267/how-can-i-override-the-style-of-the-material-ui-switch-component-when-checked'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63249267/how-can-i-override-the-style-of-the-material-ui-switch-component-when-checked%27)). They do not work. Does anyone know how I can just override the track at the theme level so that it display one color while checked and another while unchecked?

Comment: Why do you say "They do not work"? My answer to the question you linked to includes a working code sandbox.

Comment: I've updated my answer on that question to include more of the code from the sandbox so that it is clearer how to override the track.